# Maximum likelihood linear regression tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

After I implemented a LS estimation with gradient descent for a simple linear regression problem, I'm now trying to do the same with Maximum Likelihood.
[image]
I used this equation from [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineare_Regression#Maximum-Likelihood-Sch.C3.A4tzung). The maximum has to be found.

```
train_X = np.random.rand(100, 1) # all values [0-1)
train_Y = train_X
X = tf.placeholder("float", None)
Y = tf.placeholder("float", None)
theta_0 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn())
theta_1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn())
var = tf.Variable(0.5)

hypothesis = tf.add(theta_0, tf.mul(X, theta_1))
lhf = 1 * (50 * np.log(2*np.pi) + 50 * tf.log(var) + (1/(2*var)) * tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(hypothesis - Y, 2)))
op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(lhf)
```

This code works, but I still have some questions about it:

- If I change the lhf function from `1 *` to `-1 *` and minimize `-lhf` (according to the equation), it does not work. But why?
- The value for lhf goes up and down during optimization. Shouldn't it only change in one direction?
- The value for lhf sometimes is a NaN during optimization. How can I avoid that?
- In the equation, σ² is the variance of the error (right?). My values are perfectly on a line. Why do I get a value of var above 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms in your question indicate a common problem: the learning rate or step size might be too high for the problem.

The zig-zag behaviour, where the function to be maximized goes up and down, is usual when the learning rate is too high. Specially when you get NaNs.

The simplest solution is to lower the learning rate, by dividing your current learning rate by 10 until the learning curve is smooth and there are no NaNs or up-down behavior.

As you are using TensorFlow you can also try AdamOptimizer as this adjust the learning rate dynamically as you train.

Comment: I changed the learning rate to 0.000001 and it does indeed work (no NaN, monotonic decrease), however it now takes very long to get good results. Why is it so much harder to get a result than with least squares, if they are supposed to be basically the same?

Comment: @schoeberl I am not absolutely sure, it could be that the error surfaces are radically different, as least squares might have a much smoother error surface. Did you try ADAM?